# Filter list of files using an array of regular expressions (regex)

Tags: powershell

How can I change this so that I can cycle through a list of files and compare them all to an array of regular expressions?

```
$Regex_FileList = @"
TestFile_53-1227.txt^Home/Client/
Testfile_R-122719.txt^Home/Client/
TestingAFile1219.csv^Home/Client/ 
Test_PMT_122719.txt^Home/Client/
This_is_a_TEST_122719.txt^Home/folder/
"@


$Regex_1 = "^TestFile_R-\d{1,6}"
$Regex_2 = "This_is_a_TEST_\d{1,6}\.txt"
$Regex_3 = "^Test_NB"


$Regex_Array = @($Regex_1,$Regex_2,$Regex_3)

[array]$files = $Regex_FileList -split '\r?\n'

$files = $files | Where-Object {$_} #filter out empty array vals

$finalfiles = @()

for($i;$i -lt $files.count;$i++){

    $finalfiles = $files | Where {$_ -notmatch $Regex_Array[$i]}

}

$finalfiles
```

I believe my problem is this particular line: `$finalfiles = $files | Where {$_ -notmatch $Regex_Array[$i]}`

If I do something like `$files | Where {$_ -notmatch "^This"}` of course the regex works, it takes `This_is_a_TEST_122719.txt^Home/folder/` out of my `$Regex_FileList`. If I change it back to using `$Regex_Array[$i]` then the $finalfiles variable ends up blank.

I also tried this instead of the for loop `$files | ForEach-Object { if($_ -notmatch $Regex_Array){$finalfiles += $_} }`

Another thing I tried:

```
for($i;$i -lt $Regex_FileList.count;$i++){
    foreach($regex in $Regex_FileList){
        if($files[$i] -notmatch $_){
        $finalfiles += $files[$i]
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: [1] you really otta include the  error message that you get. put the FULL text in your Question _as text_. [2] what are you actually trying to do? please show the inputs and the matching outputs ... again, in your Question as text.

Comment: [3] the fie list  is showing directories, not files. or is the `^Home/folder/` supposed to be at the start?

Comment: Hi Lee, I did say that the $finalfiles ends up blank. I don't have any errors because the code runs.

Comment: is the `^Home/folder/ supposed to be at the start?`
This is a list I've built of filenames and FTP folders. I parse that out later no problem. I'm doing the regex on the whole line though before parsing takes place.

Comment: when i run your code in ps5.1 in the ISE and in the console, i get >>> `Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At line:25 char:35
+     $finalfiles = $files | Where {$_ -notmatch $Regex_Array[$i]}
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex` <<<

Comment: Strange I don't get that but I am aware that the $finalfiles variable is null. I'm trying to fix that specifically.

Comment: your `$Regex_FileList` does not show valid files names. what is that supposed to be?

Comment: Those are real test files from a real FTP, it doesn't get any more real than that. I'm doing this later if this helps you understand why it's like that.     `$filename = $item.split('^')[0]` & `$filePath = $item.split('^')[1]` but that doesn't really have anything to do with anything. If you are unable to help with the example above then I can just wait for somebody else who knows. It doesn't really matter what's in there, I just need the regex to get a proper match specifically checking each value of my regex array.

Comment: perhaps you should start from the beginning and explain what you have as input, what you want as output, and what you think needs to be done to get from one to the other. your current explanation and code are ... confusing. if you are unwilling to clarify things, i will drop out & let others try to decipher your problem ... [*grin*]

Comment: I'm looking to use my Regex_Array as the input for the regex, so that each of my regex strings are looked at. I want to return the lines from $Regex_Filelist that do not match the elements of my $Regex_Array

Comment: i think i have finally managed to guess what you want. [*grin*] please take a look at my Answer. feel free to ask any questions you have - the techniques may be more idiosyncratic that perhaps is proper. [*blush*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another pretty simple way.  All you need is the comma operator to make arrays.  The line property from select-string has the actual string result.

```
$FileList = 'TestFile_53-1227.txt^Home/Client/',
  'Testfile_R-122719.txt^Home/Client/',
  'TestingAFile1219.csv^Home/Client/',
  'Test_PMT_122719.txt^Home/Client/',
  'This_is_a_TEST_122719.txt^Home/folder/'

$PatternList = '^TestFile_R-\d{1,6}',
  'This_is_a_TEST_\d{1,6}\.txt',
  '^Test_NB'

$filelist | select-string -notmatch $patternlist | foreach line

# output
TestFile_53-1227.txt^Home/Client/
TestingAFile1219.csv^Home/Client/
Test_PMT_122719.txt^Home/Client/
```

Comment: ooo! that is so nifty ... [*grin*] i keep forgetting that the `-Pattern <String[]>` parameter of `Select-String` will accept an array of patterns and check them all.

Comment: Thank you JS, it seems it was easy for you to understand my question, and you helped me learn something new!

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be the overly convoluted steps you chose to take. when i run your code on win7ps5.1, i get the following error ...

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At line:25 char:35
+     $finalfiles = $files | Where {$_ -notmatch $Regex_Array[$i]}
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
```

i cannot understand your logic, so i gave up on that. [*blush*]

here is how i would find the strings that DO NOT match your regex pattern list ...

what it does ...

- builds a here-string, splits it into lines, and puts the results into an array
- builds a regex pattern list
- converts that pattern list into a regex OR structure by joing the items with `|` [the regex OR symbol]
- runs `-notmatch` against the input list using the regex pattern
- stores that in `$NonMatches`
- displays it on the screen

the code ...

```
$Regex_FileList = @"
TestFile_53-1227.txt^Home/Client/
Testfile_R-122719.txt^Home/Client/
TestingAFile1219.csv^Home/Client/ 
Test_PMT_122719.txt^Home/Client/
This_is_a_TEST_122719.txt^Home/folder/
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine


$PatternList = @(
    '^TestFile_R-\d{1,6}'
    'This_is_a_TEST_\d{1,6}\.txt'
    '^Test_NB'
    )

$RegexPatterList = $PatternList -join '|'

$NonMatches = $Regex_FileList -notmatch $RegexPatterList

$NonMatches
```

output ...

```
TestFile_53-1227.txt^Home/Client/
TestingAFile1219.csv^Home/Client/ 
Test_PMT_122719.txt^Home/Client/
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @shadoe2020 - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]